# Lorentz transformation relations (in AdS space) between coordinates of observers derived from the generators of symmetries in the AdS space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, string-theory, ads-cft

I have a question related to the Anti de Sitter Space in General Relativity. Please help me understand it:

In Anti de Sitter (AdS) spacetime, the symmetry generator operators are associated with isometries that preserve the AdS metric. For AdS spacetime in
d+1 dimensions, the isometry group is SO(d,2).

Among these operators, the Lorentz generators correspond to rotations and boosts. They can be written in terms of the coordinates and momenta as:
$M_{ab}$ =
$x_a   \frac{\partial}{\partial x_b} - x_b  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_a} $ + $M_{ab}^{spin}$

where $M_{ab}^{spin}$ are the generators associated with spin transformations.

The presence of Lorentz generators in the symmetry algebra of AdS spacetime implies that there are boost symmetries, similar to those in Minkowski spacetime. This indicates that you can indeed form Lorentz transformations connecting the coordinates of two observers moving in AdS space, just as you would in flat spacetime.

*The form of the Lorentz transformation remains the same in AdS spacetime as it is in flat spacetime.* However, the interpretation and implications of these transformations can be different due to the curvature and geometry of AdS spacetime. My first doubt is:

*How to derive the expressions of the Lorentz transformations of AdS space from the expressions of generators of symmetries (which we know in the form of operators) in the AdS space?*